# What does SCoTLASS stand for

Tags: statistics, principal-component-analysis

To obtain sparse principal components, there's a technique called SCoLASS. Does anyone know what this acronym stands for? I suppose LASS stands for lasso, as it puts a constraint on an l_1-norm, but what does the rest stand for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of googling quickly found the original reference (*A modified principal component technique based on the LASSO* by Jolliffe, Trendafilov and Uddin), where they say “We call the new technique SCoTLASS (Simplified Component Technique-LASSO)”.